# Possible values returned from the _messagecontext personalisation string

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm following the [personalization string documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) and need clarification on the `_messagecontext` string. Specifically, I want to understand under what context the following values would be returned. The provided descriptions resemble a translated fortune cookie:

- `VIEWSENT` "Display the non-subscriber link to preview content"
- `VALIDATION` "Display information corresponding to the validate option in Marketing Cloud"
- `LINKRESOLUTION` "Display resolved dynamic script at click time"
- `SITE` "Display CloudPage content"

I would have assumed that the last value (`SITE`) is returned when content is viewed on a page in CloudPages, but that has the value `LANDINGPAGE` (for both CloudPage resource files and landing pages), so I'm still at a loss on this one. If anyone could shed any light on these four values, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Leaving as a comment because this is a guess: `VIEWSENT` could be to do with social sharing, or maybe the Email Logging (the one that saves .eml files on FTP). `VALIDATION` occurs before a send and when you click the validate option (I'm actually a little bit sure about this one). `LINKRESOLUTION` and `SITE` are anyone's guess

Comment: I'm guessing `LANDINGPAGE` is for classic microsites whereas `SITE` is for CloudPages

Comment: @eliotharper did you find out more about this during the past years?

Comment: @DonL I documented the complete list at https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/